# Working out a formula for a series of numbers which are NOT an X-Y set

Tags: logic, algorithms

I need to find a formula, which can calculate the value of M from the given value, O. The values are as follows:

O

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 …

M

1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 …

Note that the values are paired, so where O = 2, M = 4, and that the reason the formula is required is so, for example, I were given the O value of 10, I could work out that its M value is equal to 1024.

I have tried (with no success) plugging these values in to a linear graph formula (Y = MX+C), but had no success, because the numbers in the M set do not plot a straight line (I assume?). I have also worked out that, where the numbers are even, M = 1/2*O^3, but that this is not the case for the odd numbers (the closest to this I can figure out is that for odd numbers, M = [o+1]^2*2). This, however, is not adequate (if there is better available) for my purposes, as if I have one formula, I can but plug the values in, where as if I have two, I have to first determine if the number is odd or even (a problem as this equation is for a program I am developing, and determining this will take up precious (though little) space).

Therefore, my questions are these:

1. Is there a formula for this particular problem? I can see a pattern in both sets of numbers, but cannot work out the connection between the two sets.
2. is there a way of working out such problems so that in future, I do not have to go asking math geniuses for the answer?

Thanks so much for your help,
Thomas

Comment: You can try with : $2^n$.

Comment: Ask yourself, for the sequence M, "how do I obtain the following term from the previous?"  Go from there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your sequence $M$.  Now, let's start with $1$.  How do you get from $1$ to $2$?  Well there are a couple of obvious options.  First, you could add $1$ to $1$ to get $2$, or the other would be to multiply $1$ by $2$.  Now, from $2$, how do you get from $2$ to $4$?  Well, the same techniques yields that we can add $2$ to $2$ or multiply $2$ by $2$.  So while adding requires different terms from $1\rightarrow 2$ and $2\rightarrow 4$, we can multiply both by $2$ to yield the result.  This continues from $4\rightarrow 8$.  Thus we can see that.
$$2=2$$
$$2\cdot 2=4$$
$$2\cdot 2\cdot 2=8$$
By the definition of exponentiation, $2\cdot 2=2^2,$ and $2\cdot 2\cdot 2=2^3$  Now can you see the correspondence between your sets $O$ and $M$?  The set $O$ is simply the exponent of $2$ in set $M$.  Using the rules of exponentiation, we can see that $2^0=1$.  Thus
$$2^0=1$$
$$2^1=2$$
$$2^2=4$$
$$2^3=8$$
$$2^4=16$$
Therefore the $n$-th term of your sequence $M$ can be found by raising $2$ to the $n$-th term of the sequence $O$.  Or in algebraic terms, 
$$a_n=2^n$$
where $a_n$ denotes the $n$-th term of $M$.

Comment: Iceman, Thanks, that's brilliant!:-)